# Pandas Dataframe: New Column that uses Country if Province is empty, else use the Province

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The meat of what I'm trying to do can be seen at the bottom.
Here's the dataset I'm using: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

What I want is to add to ['Names'] the data from ['Province/State'] if it isn't empty, else the data from ['Country/Region'].

I'm building an interactive heat map using plotly, and it works. But the problem is, there are multiple markers named "Canada" (for each of the states there) and Greenland is named "Denmark," because in the CSV file, "Greenland" is under "State/Province" and "Denmark" is under "Country/Region."

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)


confirmed_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'
deaths_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv'
yesterdays_date = yesterday.strftime('%-m/%d/%y') 

confirmed = pd.read_csv(confirmed_url)
deaths = pd.read_csv(deaths_url)
confirmed.iloc[0]['Country/Region'] #Test

for place in deaths[['Province/State','Country/Region']]:
    if place is float:
        deaths_names.append('Country/Region')
    else:
        deaths_names.append('Province/State')

confirmed['Name'] = df(confirmed_names)
deaths['Name'] = df(deaths_names)
```

Comment: is `deaths_names` a list?

Answer (score -1):

This worked:

```
def names_column(frame, lst): #Makes a new column called Name
    for i in range(len(frame)):
        if type(frame['Province/State'][i]) is str:
            lst.append(frame['Province/State'][i])
        else:
            lst.append(frame['Country/Region'][i])
    frame['Name'] = df(lst)

names_column(confirmed, confirmed_names)
names_column(deaths, deaths_names)
```